# Vi - insert mode doesn't work in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, vi

I am working on Ubuntu 12.10. Insert mode in vi isn't working.

[image: file open in Vi in gnome-terminal]

When I hit <kbd>i</kbd> to go insert mode, nothing happens. On hitting <kbd>i</kbd> again writes `i` on terminal, but <kbd><-backspace</kbd> doesn't remove the character. Only <kbd>Delete</kbd> works there.
Do I need to configure anywhere?

Comment: From the description, insert mode is working fine.  The issue with backspace not working will just be due to the default vim being restricted to "vi compatibility" mode.  Installing the "vim" package will remove that from the default config and let you use all vim features.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Installing **VIM** will probably solve that issue

```
sudo aptitude install vim
```

it actually has to work though, it might be that compatibility mode is on therefore you will be in the insert mode but VI won't tell you.

Either way using vim is recommended, its basically **V** i  **IM** proved.

Comment: "sudo apt-get install vim" command worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

Its not that insert mode doesnt work. But the vi editor you are using is the older version and is different to use than our usual editors. Get updated version of vi editor by-

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```